# Java Graphics performance issue when drawing transparent shapes

Tags: java, performance, particles

I've started working on a game engine for fun with no external libraries. I've started creating a simple particle system and I've come to some huge performance issues. I have the following frawing method for the particle (the particle calls this):

```
public void renderParticle(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setPaint(color);
        g2d.fillOval(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), w, h);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

This works just fine, 5000 particles (16 x 16) can be rendered with around 33 FPS. However, if I try to add alpha:

```
public void renderParticle(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color, int alpha) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        Color col = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), 128);
        g2d.setPaint(col);
        g2d.fillOval(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), w, h);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

Only 200 of them just makes the FPS drop to 12. Any idea to boost the performance? I've seen java particle systems (only using builtin libs) with even 100 000 particles running just fine.

My particle class:

```
public class Particle extends Entity {

    protected Vector2f velocity;

    protected double life;
    protected double maxLife;

    protected Vector2f size;
    protected Vector2f maxSize;
    protected Vector2f growth;

    protected Color color;

    public Particle(Vector2f position, float speed, float angles, double life, Vector2f size, Vector2f growth, Vector2f maxSize, Color color) {
        super(position);

        double angInRad = Math.toRadians(angles);
        this.velocity = new Vector2f((float) (speed * Math.cos(angInRad)), (float) (-speed * Math.sin(angInRad)));

        this.color = color;

        this.life = life;
        this.maxLife = life;

        this.size = size;
        this.growth = growth;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public Particle(Vector2f position, float speed, float angles, double life, Vector2f size, Color color) {
        super(position);

        double angInRad = Math.toRadians(angles);
        this.velocity = new Vector2f((float) (speed * Math.cos(angInRad)), (float) (-speed * Math.sin(angInRad)));

        this.color = color;

        this.life = life;
        this.maxLife = life;

        this.size = size;
    }

    public Particle(Vector2f position, float speed, float angles, double life, Color color) {
        super(position);

        double angInRad = Math.toRadians(angles);
        this.velocity = new Vector2f((float) (speed * Math.cos(angInRad)), (float) (-speed * Math.sin(angInRad)));

        this.color = color;

        this.life = life;
        this.maxLife = life;
    }

    public Particle(Vector2f position, float speed, float angles, Color color) {
        super(position);

        double angInRad = Math.toRadians(angles);
        this.velocity = new Vector2f((float) (speed * Math.cos(angInRad)), (float) (-speed * Math.sin(angInRad)));

        this.color = color;
    }

    public void update(double delta) {
        life -= delta;

        this.position.x += this.velocity.x * delta;
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y * delta;

        if (this.size.x < Math.abs(maxSize.x)) {
            this.size.x += this.growth.x * delta;
            this.size.y += this.growth.y * delta;
        }
    }

    public void render(Renderer renderer) {
        renderer.renderParticle((int) position.x, (int) position.y, (int) size.x, (int) size.y, color, (int) (life / maxLife * 100));
    }

    public void setLife(double life) {
        this.life = life;
        this.maxLife = life;
    }

    public void setGrowth(Vector2f g) {
        this.growth = g;
    }

    public void setMaxSize(Vector2f s) {
        this.maxSize = s;
    }

    public void setSize(Vector2f s) {
        this.size = s;
    }

    public double getLife() {
        return life;
    }
}
```

And my renderer is basicly the renderParticle() method.
I create the particles like this:

```
particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            Color col = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
            Particle p = new Particle(new Vector2f(300, 300), rand.nextFloat() * 100 + 1, rand.nextFloat() * 360, col);
            p.setSize(new Vector2f(16, 16));
            p.setGrowth(new Vector2f(10, 10));
            p.setMaxSize(new Vector2f(32, 32));
            p.setLife(2);
            particles.add(p);
        }
```

Updating and rendering:

```
public void update(double delta) {
        for (int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
            particles.get(i).update(delta);
            if (particles.get(i).getLife() <= 0) particles.remove(i);
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        for (int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
            particles.get(i).render(renderer);
        }
    }
```

I've simplified the renderParticle() but there's no change:

```
public void renderParticle(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color, int alpha) {
    Color col = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), 128);
    g.setColor(col);
    g.fillOval(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), w, h);
}
```

Comment: Goodness. You might want to share your graphics object between all your particles for starters. You should really profile your code for more information. With the profile results you'll be able to focus your efforts on the slowest code.

Comment: Well I've edited my post and added the particle class

Comment: No, we don't need more code. We need the information provided by the profiler. However, at that point, I imagine you'll answer your own question and know where the slow parts are.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you need. I profiled my program but I knew already that the issue is with the transparent drawing. At 1.0 it's no issue but any other drops the FPS.

Comment: More advanced profiling. Frames per second is one of the most basic forms of profiling and tells us very little about what's actually happening. Advanced profiling will tell you line by line how much time your program is taking to execute and how long it spends in each method. Beyond that you'll have to realize you're using functionality in Java that wasn't created for high performance games. Particle rendering is a challenging task.

Comment: What should I use instead of functionality?

Comment: This isn't the place for those types of discussions.